# How do `nm` choose the character to print for each symbol type?

Tags: c, elf, nm

I'm currently doing a `nm` like program, to print the symbols of an ELF file with their addresses and their type.

The typical output is something like :

```
$ nm ./my_exec      
0000000000003d28 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000003f28 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000002000 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
```

The first column is the symbol address, the second is the symbol type and the third, the symbol name.

The man indicates the meaning for each character, upper-case is a global symbol, lower-case is local symbol etc...

But I don't understand *how* it choose which character to use.

I'm using the `Gelf` library and I didn't see a field from where I could determine the character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nm` chooses the character mostly based on the section in which the symbol appears. ELF is specified in [the System V ABI](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf); pages 4-22 and following describe the symbol table, which include two fields, `st_info` and `st_shndx`, and these determine [the character shown by `nm`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.38/binutils/nm.html).

The symbol binding (`ELF32_ST_BIND(st_info)`) determines whether the symbol is local (lowercase in `nm`), global (uppercase), or weak (`v`, `w`). `sh_shndx` points to the section containing the symbol, and many of `nm`’s characters reflect this, either as an explicit section (`b`, `d`...), or as a value with special meaning (*e.g.* `u` for `SHN_UNDEF`, undefined symbols).

So you won’t find a single value which directly corresponds to the character shown by `nm`, but the above should give you enough information to interpret the values described in the ABI specification.